# Failed to build Java Mail API 1.4.5 with maven-3.0.4

Tags: maven, jakarta-mail, netbeans-7

I am trying to build Java Mail 1.4.5 with Maven-3.0.4 using default settings of maven.

It is getting failed to build due to following errors -

> [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : [INFO]
>   ----------------------------------------------------------- [ERROR] \Workarea\mySourceData\src\Mail\mail\src\main\java\javax\mail\Session.java:[210,37]
>   cannot find symbol symbol : variable Version location: class
>   javax.mail.Session [ERROR]
>   \Workarea\mySourceData\src\Mail\mail\src\main\java\javax\mail\Session.java:[369,47]
>   cannot find symbol symbol : variable Version location: class
>   javax.mail.Session [ERROR]
>   \Workarea\mySourceData\src\Mail\mail\src\main\java\javax\mail\Session.java:[913,29]
>   cannot find symbol symbol : variable Version location: class
>   javax.mail.Session [ERROR]
>   \Workarea\mySourceData\src\Mail\mail\src\main\java\javax\mail\Session.java:[916,29]
>   cannot find symbol symbol : variable Version location: class
>   javax.mail.Session [ERROR]
>   \Workarea\mySourceData\src\Mail\mail\src\main\java\javax\mail\Session.java:[919,29]
>   cannot find symbol symbol : variable Version location: class
>   javax.mail.Session [ERROR]
>   \Workarea\mySourceData\src\Mail\mail\src\main\java\javax\mail\Session.java:[922,29]
>   cannot find symbol symbol : variable Version location: class
>   javax.mail.Session [ERROR]
>   \Workarea\mySourceData\src\Mail\mail\src\main\java\javax\mail\Session.java:[925,29]
>   cannot find symbol symbol : variable Version location: class
>   javax.mail.Session [ERROR]
>   \Workarea\mySourceData\src\Mail\mail\src\main\java\javax\mail\Session.java:[928,29]
>   cannot find symbol symbol : variable Version location: class
>   javax.mail.Session [INFO] 8 errors [INFO]
>   ----------------------------------------------------------- [INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------- [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------- [INFO] Total time: 1:51.197s [INFO] Finished at: Tue Jan 08 13:06:01
>   IST 2013 [INFO] Final Memory: 12M/67M [INFO]
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------- [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.
>   3.2:compile (default-compile) on project javax.mail: Compilation failure: Compil ation failure: [ERROR]
>   \Workarea\mySourceData\src\Mail\mail\src\main\java\javax\mail\Session.java:[210,37]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol : variable Version [ERROR] location:
>   class javax.mail.Session
>   [ERROR]\Workarea\mySourceData\src\Mail\mail\src\main\java\javax\mail\Session.java:[369,47]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol : variable Version [ERROR] location:
>   class javax.mail.Session [ERROR]
>   \Workarea\mySourceData\src\Mail\mail\src\main\java\javax\mail\Session.java:[913,29]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol : variable Version [ERROR] location:
>   class javax.mail.Session [ERROR]
>   \Workarea\mySourceData\src\Mail\mail\src\main\java\javax\mail\Session.java:[916,29]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol : variable Version [ERROR] location:
>   class javax.mail.Session [ERROR]
>   \Workarea\mySourceData\src\Mail\mail\src\main\java\javax\mail\Session.java:[919,29]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol : variable Version [ERROR] location:
>   class javax.mail.Session [ERROR]
>   \Workarea\mySourceData\src\Mail\mail\src\main\java\javax\mail\Session.java:[922,29]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol : variable Version [ERROR] location:
>   class javax.mail.Session
>   [ERROR]\Workarea\mySourceData\src\Mail\mail\src\main\java\javax\mail\Session.java:[925,29]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol : variable Version [ERROR] location:
>   class javax.mail.Session [ERROR]
>   \Workarea\mySourceData\src\Mail\mail\src\main\java\javax\mail\Session.java:[928,29]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol : variable Version [ERROR] location:
>   class javax.mail.Session [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal o
>   rg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile
>   (default-compile) on project javax.mail: Compilation failure at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
>   .java:213) at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
>   .java:153) at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
>   .java:145) at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
>   ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84) at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
>   ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59) at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBu
>   ild(LifecycleStarter.java:183) at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
>   eStarter.java:161) at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320) at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156) at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537) at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196) at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
>   java:57) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
>   sorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
>   cher.java:290) at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
>   a:230) at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
>   uncher.java:409) at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
>   352) Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException:
>   Compilation fail ure at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompiler
>   Mojo.java:656) at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:128) at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Default
>   BuildPluginManager.java:101) at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
>   .java:209) ... 19 more [ERROR] [ERROR] [ERROR] For more information
>   about the errors and possible solutions, please rea d the following
>   articles: [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

Same issue I am facing when I am trying to build Java Mail with netbeans - 7.2.1, it getting failed with same version issue in Session.java class.

How can I set this Version in Session.java class to get rid of this error?

If we can use nexus repository then please let me know how to set this.

Thanks,
Neelam Sharma

Answer (score 1):

JavaMail 1.4.5 needs Maven 2 to build.  I fixed it to build with Maven 3 shortly after the 1.4.5 release.  You can find the changes in the source repository if you want to backport them.

Still, the errors above don't look like they're related to the Maven version so perhaps something else is going wrong.  As I remember, I ran into similar problems when using a newer version of the compiler plugin and I had to update the build-helper plugin as well to fix it.